# Fragment ClickListener error in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have converted a RecyclerView from Activity to Fragment all work but when i click on item i have this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void fragment.MyRecyclerViewAdapter$MyClickListener.onItemClick(int, android.view.View)' on a null object reference
```

This error is in `myClickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), v);`

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView
        .Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter
        .DataObjectHolder> {
    private static String LOG_TAG = "MyRecyclerViewAdapter";
    private ArrayList<DataObject> mDataset;
    private static MyClickListener myClickListener;

    public static class DataObjectHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            implements View
            .OnClickListener {
        TextView label;
        TextView dateTime;

        public DataObjectHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            label = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            dateTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Adding Listener");
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myClickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), v); //ERROR HERE
        }
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(MyClickListener myClickListener) {
        this.myClickListener = myClickListener;
    }

    public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<DataObject> myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    @Override
    public DataObjectHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.card_view_row, parent, false);

        DataObjectHolder dataObjectHolder = new DataObjectHolder(view);
        return dataObjectHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DataObjectHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.label.setText(mDataset.get(position).getmText1());
        holder.dateTime.setText(mDataset.get(position).getmText2());
    }

    public void addItem(DataObject dataObj, int index) {
        mDataset.add(index, dataObj);
        notifyItemInserted(index);
    }

    public void deleteItem(int index) {
        mDataset.remove(index);
        notifyItemRemoved(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

    public interface MyClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(int position, View v);
    }
}
```

This code is in fragment:

```
mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) mView.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mAdapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(getDataSet());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        return mView;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling

```
public void setOnItemClickListener(MyClickListener myClickListener) {
        this.myClickListener = myClickListener;
    }
```

from anywhere.

Call this method from your adapter or fragment. Or if you do not want right now, just add **null check**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  if (myClickListener!= null) {
     myClickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), v); //ERROR HERE
  }
}
```

And add below code into Fragment class.

```
   ((MyRecyclerViewAdapter) mAdapter).setOnItemClickListener(new MyRecyclerViewAdapter.MyClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int position, View v) {
            // Implement your logic to do after clicking on any item.
        }
    });
```

Comment: @Marcus you have called itemView.setOnClickListener(this); instead.

Comment: Sorry im very new in android i can't understand your answer

Comment: @MarcusJ.Kennedy See my last update. Add this code before doing "return mView;". And I will strongly suggest that before doing such things you need to read basics. This is not a place to provide code and why a code is not working. So please take care in future

Comment: Thanks but i have an error: "Cannot resolve method setOnItemClickListener"

Answer (score 0):

Before calling the set adapter on your recyclerview call setOnItemClickListener

Answer (score 0):

I have solved with:

```
((MyRecyclerViewAdapter) mAdapter).setOnItemClickListener(new MyRecyclerViewAdapter
                .MyClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position, View v) {              
                Log.wtf("TEST", position);
            }
        });
```